# Write a program to find the greatest number in a list using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

My solution is:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 6, 101, 55, 7, 1, 3, 88, 99, 101, 6, 88, 66, 101, 6, 101, 55, 1001]
n = len(numbers)
for x in range(n):
    y = 0
    while y < n:
        if numbers[x] >= numbers[y]:
            y += 1
        else:
            break
    else:
       z = x
print(f'Greatest number = {numbers[z]}')
```

I know it's complicated but is it right?
And one more thing --- Even though I am getting my answers correct for every list of numbers i can make but pycharm is showing a warning that -- Name 'z' can be undefined.
why is that and how can I remove it//

Comment: Someone please also suggest a solution without using indexes. That would be the most important lesson

Comment: sorry I am learning python from youtube for less than 2 days so I don't know how to think simpler

Comment: In python its possible to find maximum value of a list using max(). Just do max(numbers)

Answer (score 2):

yes, it's complicated and not effective to use two loops just to find the max. Even max function can be used

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 6, 101, 55, 7, 1, 3, 88, 99, 101, 6, 88, 66, 6, 101, 55, 1001]
print(max(numbers))
```

For writing your own logic, this is in fact simpler.

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 6, 101, 55, 7, 1, 3, 88, 99, 101, 6, 88, 66, 6, 101, 55, 1001]
maxi = numbers[0]
for i in numbers:
    if i > maxi:
        maxi = i
print("Greatest number: ", maxi)
```

Comment: Thank you Mam for replying. I am just a beginner in coding (or in computer science) so I don't know if the max() function is inbuilt in python. And your second answer is amazing. again thanks as this was my first question on stack overflow :)

Comment: Please don't add spammy links to your answers. See: [What signifies "Good" self promotion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212), [some tips and advice about self-promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion), [What is the exact definition of "spam" for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260638), and [What makes something spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035)

Answer (score 1):

The `else:` block is only executed if the `while` loop ends normally, rather than by executing a `break` statement.

Since you only set `z` in the `else:` block, if the loop ends due to the `break` statement, `z` won't be set.

It may be that the mathematical logic of the two loops ensures that at least one of the inner loops will complete without executing `break`. But PyCharm can't tell that this is always true, so it warns about it.

If you're certain that there's no possibility that the loop will end without setting `z`, you can suppress the warning in PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

```
max_number = max(numbers)
print('Greatest number = {}'.format(max_number))
```

For pycharm warning, it is because the variable z defined and assigned in else block, unlike like java python is dynamically typed and doesn't require variable declaration

Comment: I have no idea why someone voted this down.  Looks like the best answer to me, except for the bad formatting.  (And you want "number" instead of "numbers").  Put triple back quotes before and after code so it gets formatted correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I have corrected the numbers mistake

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in doing z = x. Just do:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 6, 101, 55, 7, 1, 3, 88, 99, 101, 6, 88, 66, 101, 6, 101, 55, 1001]
n = len(numbers)
for x in range(n):
    y = 0
    while y < n:
        if numbers[x] >= numbers[y]:
            y += 1
        else:
            break

print(f'Greatest number = {numbers[z]}')
```

Comment: At the end, you'll print `numbers[z]` and you haven't assigned anything to `z`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using C/C++ approach to solve it by python has a lot of built-in functions that can make your life much easier. In this case, you can use **[max()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max)** function.

The shortest way

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 6, 101, 55, 7, 1, 3, 88, 99, 101, 6, 88, 66, 101, 6, 101, 55, 1001]

print(f'Greatest number = {max(numbers)}')
Greatest number = 1001
```

You recieve this notification because **z** variable is declared only in **else** block. And if your code will exit from **while** block (not in this case, but anyway) and never goes to **else**, you will recieve an error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'z' referenced before assignment
```

Simple example:

```
def test(x):
   ...:     if x == 1:
   ...:         z = x
   ...:     else:
   ...:         pass
   ...:     print(z)
   ...:     
test(1)
1
test(2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/terin/regru/venvs/.dl/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-13-14ddcd275974>", line 1, in <module>
    test(2)
  File "<ipython-input-11-43eaa101b10d>", line 6, in test
    print(z)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'z' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: yes, when I declare it before while loop error is gone. haha thanks